# Creating a square matrix of ratios in R

Tags: r, matrix

Pretty new to R, so I'm trying to figure out some shortcuts for inputting values rather than individually. I'd like to create a 4x4 matrix, where the values are ratios. That is, I have 4 values - let's say s1, s2, s3, and s4 - and each entry in the matrix is si/sj (not sure if you can do subscripts, but I think you understand). So, each entry on the diagonal would be 1, and the others would be a ratio.
If I have a vector `s <- vec(c(1, 2, 3, 4)`, for example, how can I make this matrix without calculating each ratio? Thanks!

Comment: is this what you want? `x <- 1:4; outer(x, x, '/')`

Comment: Yes, that does it! Thanks so much!